# mysqltuner.pl on a windows 2008 server r2

Tags: mysql, windows, windows-server-2008, mysqltuner

I usually use linux for mysql and have something called mysqltuner.pl and this is great but we have a mysql server on a windows 2008 r2 server that we have and was wondering if any of you know of something simular to mysqltuner that i can use.  I have seen on the project page that they have a windows version but it only works on winXP.

Any pointers or if anyone has ported there own version would be great.

many thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recommended MySQL tuning utility for Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833397/recommended-mysql-tuning-utility-for-windows)

Comment: @peter are you mental, this post is 2011   whats more is, you link back  to a question that has no solution, if anything you should be back-linking there question to this one, you are a very strange person mr chapman

Comment: Probably. Back-linking sound like a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a windows version you can use at

http://gggeek.altervista.org/sw/mysqltuner-win.pl

It uses cygwin.

Comment: @eljakim the link above is to a 2008 version of mysqltuner.pl.  In 2018, this would probably not be a good idea to use a version this old.

Answer (score 0):

It's now 2020, Wilson asked in 2018 if there was a newer version than what I answered in 2011.

So, 9 years after my original answer:
https://github.com/pmachapman/mysqltuner/