# Any MySQLTuner equivalent/alternative for Windows?

Tags: mysql, windows, performance, mysqltuner

I know auto tuning has its limits, but it would be great to quickly determine reasonable starting points for my Windows MySQL InnoDB configuration (`innodb_additional_mem_pool_size, innodb_buffer_pool_size, innodb_log_file_size, innodb_log_buffer_size`), given the RAM that I want to allocate to MySQL (512 Mo from a total 4 GB installed).
I found [this previous similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667185/mysqltuner-pl-on-a-windows-2008-server-r2) but it had no answer.

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem as you, so have ported MySQLTuner to Windows - you can download it from http://mysqltuner.codeplex.com/. The alternative is to run mysqltuner.pl from a Linux box, remote connecting to your Windows MySQL server, however this does not produce as accurate results.